# Dynamically add Components to an Entity

Tags: swift, architecture, sprite-kit

In my game, I have an entity which is an empty robot, and some components which are parts for building that robot(arm, head, weapon, tool, etc) and each part consists of different types. What I want is for the player to starting building the robot by dynamically adding parts to it.
My entity class has properties like this:

```
var arm: Component!
var head: Component!
var legs: Component!
var weapon: Component!
```

Basically, the robot entity has a property for every possible component in the game, and when I get new ideas for components I have to create properties for them in the robot class, and I have a function that assigns each property to the component that the player adds. The reason I'm doing that is to be able to access them from an outside class like this:

```
robot.weapon.shoot()
robot.legs.move()
```

But what I want is for the robot entity to not have any component reference in it at the start, I want them to be added dynamically depending on the player's choices and still be able to access them as I have shown above, meaning that the class would be empty and when the player adds a component (for example a pistol) a property like that would appear, or some sort of a way that makes that component a part of that entity:

```
var weapon: Component = Pistol()
```

I'm not sure if it's even possible to do that.

PS: I'm not using the component-entity system that is built in GamePlayKit and I don't want to.

Comment: This is exactly what GamePlayKit does, why you don't want use it?

Comment: In a more general context, what you want to do is called *dependency injection*.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) pattern. You have to make classes for your robot components, that represent an absence of a special action. For example, you may create `AbsentWeapon` class and it's `shoot()` must do nothing in your game. Or it could sent a message to event control class about an attempt to shoot without a weapon (that depends on your design).

You could make those classes singleton-like objects to ease your checks (`if myWeapon == EmptyComponents.getEmptyWeapon() {...}`)